# JavaScript functions failing after upgrading Karate to 1.4.0

Tags: karate

I have a set of API tests which are working in Karate 1.3.1. I upgraded it to 1.4.0 and the JS functions started failing with

```
01: utils.sleep(30)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (sleep) on {now={}, toDate={}, getToday={}, dateAdd={}, formatDate={}, sleep={}, logResult={}} failed due to: Message not supported.
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Here is how my karate-config and utils (sample of only one function) files look like

**karate-config.js**

```
 // Add JS functions
  var js = karate.callSingle('classpath:common/utils.js', config);
// Add utils
  config.utils = js.utils;
```

**utils.js**

```
function addUtils(config) { 

    // Add utility functions
    config['utils'] = {

    // Sleep for a number of milliseconds
        sleep: function(millis) {
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(millis);
        }
    }

    return config;
}
```

Updated **POM file** with

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Java version used - "17.0.7"

Comment: sorry, this is the kind of question we insist on a way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - by the way we absolutely don't recommend mixing JS functions with `callSingle()` https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karatecallsingle

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Looking into updating the way JS functions are used and I will submit an issue if the errors still persist. Thanks!